# url for sending messages to whomever messaged me

Tags: node.js, bots, slack-api, chatbot

I have created a slack app. Its a chatbot. I named it jsbot.

**Working of my bot:**

- someone `messages` to my `bot`
- my `bot` take that `message` and go to `dialogflow (api.ai)`
- `dialogflow` returns me an `action` depending on the `message`.
- I find a `key` matching that `action` in my `database` and the `database` returns me the `value` corresponding to the matching `key`.
- I send that `value` to `whomever messaged me`.

**Problem:**

currently I am sending the final message to `slack incoming webhook` and it works fine. Now one of my `slackteam member`s installed my `app`.

He sends a message to my app. My app responds to me instead I expect it to respond my friend.

**Code:**

Here is the code that my bot responds:

```
request({
    uri: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX',
    method: 'POST',
    json: message
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('Successfully sent message');
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

I think each user will have different uri for `incoming-webhook`. So, I am in search for a url that will send the message to the specific user. When user requested me, I saved the user, so I can send message to that same user.

Anybody know the url of slack webhook which allows me to send message by user_id?

Answer (score 0):

[Incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) are working a bit differently on Slack. You do not need or want an individual webhook URL per user. Instead you can just use the same incoming webhook URL to send messages to different users.

All you need to do is to provide the user ID of the receiving user as channel parameter (thus overriding the default channel).

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"channel": "U12345678", "text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX
```

Comment: btw. since you already have a Slack app, you may want to look into using the API methods [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), instead of an incoming webhooks. There you can also use the userid as channel parameter.

Comment: I used incoming-webhooks and passed userid to channel as per your guideline. But still I have the same issue.

Comment: I also took a look at API method chat.postMessage but it requires a token and I don't know where to get token from.

Comment: Also, can you please explain me the last parameter of my url? I mean in `https://hooks.slack.com/services/TTT/BBB/XXX` `TTT` means `team_id`, `BBB` means `bot_id`, then what is the meaning of `XXX`?

Comment: what you mean by "same issue". if the message still goes to you, instead of the other user you apparently are using the wrong user_id

Comment: as I said the webhook URL has nothing to do with a user. they are linked to a team and an app (which is the incoming webhook app) but that it. the rest is random.

Comment: if you want to learn more about how to use the web API, check out the excellent [offical documentation](https://api.slack.com/) or post a another question.

Comment: By "same issue" I mean that now I am passing the user id of my friend as mentioned by you. But still I am getting the response. I have also verified the user id of my friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164249/discussion-between-erik-kalkoken-and-vishal).